# excel VBA Range or cells()?

Tags: excel, vba

So, I'm trying to write a user friendly macro for easy sales recording.
I've completed all the input and calculation part, however when I tried to write the result in excel spread sheet using the **cell()** function, I can only write in string.

```
Range("A2").Select
ActiveCell.End(xlToRight).Select
lastcolumn = ActiveCell.Column
'MsgBox lastcolumn
If lastcolumn = 16384 Then
lastcolumn = 1
End If
Cells(16, lastcolumn + 1).Select
If lbl_scfe = "" Then
Cells(2, lastcolumn + 1).Value = 0
Else
Cells(2, lastcolumn + 1).Value = lbl_scfe
End If
```

I've also wrote a short code to test if the **range** function would work...

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
val_cfe_1 = Val(TextBox1)
val_cfe_2 = Val(TextBox2)
coffee = val_cfe_1 * 10 + val_cfe_2
Label1 = coffee
Range("a1") = coffee
Range("a2") = Label1
Cells(2, 1) = coffee
Cells(2, 2) = Label1
End Sub
```

Both codes had a userform to go with it, the **range** function output both in double data type, cells(2,2) output in strings, and

```
Cells(2, 1) = coffee
```

yield no output in the cell.
So should I assume that **Cells()** function can only input string? Or am I not using the function correctly...
If I can't use **cells()** function, then how can I write a **range** function that can automatically go to the last column and goes to individual row?
Thanks

Comment: Using `Cells(2, 1) = coffee` should be fine.  Lots of queries/questions: 1. How have you `Dim`'d `coffee`,  `val_cfe_1` and `val_cfe_2` (please show us code).  2.   What are you getting in cell `A1`?  3. Have you stepped through the debugger to see what values you are getting for `coffee`,  `val_cfe_1` and `val_cfe_2`?

Answer (score 0):

You should use

```
Cells(2, 1).Value = coffee
```

instead of just

```
Cells(2, 1) = coffee
```

Otherwise you compare the cell with `coffee`, instead of the cells value.

Comment: Value is the default property of a Range object, so these two lines of code are equivalent